# Reference a CSS file from a shared project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an intranet solution with multiple projects and I'm trying to use a Shared Layout between the projects via RazorGenerator (https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator). Each project is going to use the same set of CSS/JS files. I'm thinking of sharing these by using a shared project or solution folder and storing the files inside of these. However, I am not sure how to reference these from my cshtml files.

Here is the the solution structure:
[Solution Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHUVx.png)

ViewLibrary is the shared layout. Web Application 1 is an application that will use the ViewLibrary for the common layout and implement its own functionality within. SharedContent is currently a shared project with the files I'm trying to use across all projects.

When I'm referencing these in the common _Layout.cshtml file, what would I use in place of the href to access these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/SharedProject/material.css">
```